# Fetch using asysnc await inside try catch block

Tags: reactjs, ajax, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, fetch

I am unable to run the following code where I try to fetch data from a URL. It is going to catch block always despite getting response from the server.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSomeData = async () => {
        try {
            await fetch(api);
            if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            const json = await response.json();
            setData(json);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(message);
        };
    }
    fetchSomeData();
  }, [api]);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `response.ok`? In your code it is undefined since I don't see `response` being defined anywhere, therefore the check fails and you will throw an error, which is subsequently being caught by `catch`.

I suppose you meant to assign the response from the fetch, i.e.:

```
try {
    // Assign the resolved promise payload to `response` const
    const response = await fetch(api);

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(message);
};
```

Comment: Cool..Thanks...just one last question...is a try...catch block a good way of handling errors which may be thrown from the fetch call...I think there is a fetch().then() ...but not sure how to use that if I am using the async...await here (which is why i have used try..catch block)

Comment: It's really up to you. Personally I prefer the async/await approach because I don't have to create another level of nesting in `.then()`

Comment: ok...and for the error handling, you use try...catch block as used above? Basically I wanted to understand if the above pattern (try...catch block) is standard when using fetch

Comment: Yes I would do that.